# epiphany-browser doesn't work on wsl2

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, browser

I have installed epiphany-browser on wsl2, it opens normally but I can't do anything like it doesn't have internet connection.

When I open at first I get error like this

```
** (epiphany:361): WARNING **: 08:53:17.542: Failed to search secrets in password schema: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL) (available: EXTERNAL)
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

then I get errors like this

```
(WebKitWebProcess:2): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:53:17.666: cannot open display: 172.21.16.1:0

** (epiphany:361): WARNING **: 08:53:17.668: Web process crashed
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

And when I close the browser I get error like this

```
(epiphany:361): dconf-WARNING **: 08:53:32.844: failed to commit changes to dconf: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL) (available: EXTERNAL)

(epiphany:361): dconf-WARNING **: 08:53:32.844: failed to commit changes to dconf: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL) (available: EXTERNAL)
```

`winver.exe` output:
`Windows 10 21H1 OS Build 19043.985`

`uname -a` output:
`Linux DESKTOP-T5NQ5IF 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I installed it with help of this website: http://browsingthenet.blogspot.com/2016/11/how-to-run-epiphany-web-browser-in.html

X11 works with something simple as xlock, xeyes, etc.

What is the issue here ?

Comment: ever figure this out?